# Python setup.py install failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have a simple dir structure

```
gpp/
   .. a.py
   .. setup.py
```

and in setup.py

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

version = '0.1.0'

setup(
    name = 'gpp',
    version = version,
    py_modules = ['a'],
    )
```

then I try to install this in my own machine by

```
python setup.py install
```

the egg show up in the correct location, I am using anaconda and virtual env of anaconda, so ~/anaconda/envs/palladium-gp/lib/python3.4/site-packages

but it is only in egg

```
gpp-0.1.0-py3.4.egg
```

unzip , and import fails

```
python
import gpp
```

failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory structure should be:

```
gpp/
   .. __init__.py
   .. a.py
setup.py
```

and you would need to specify the package:

```
setup(
    name = 'gpp',
    version = version,
    packages=['gpp', 'gpp.a'],
)
```

You can then import:

```
from gpp import a
```

or:

```
import gpp.a
```